# Why is JavaScript code parsed during initial page load?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, adsense

I have added this Adsense (for content) code on my page to display 1 ad:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
</script>
<ins
 class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:250px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
 data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"></ins>
<script type="text/javascript">
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

All the code is located where the ad is displayed.

However Chrome PageSpeed tells me that the code is not asynced:

```
68.6KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load.
Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.
http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/.../ads?... (45.4KiB of inline JavaScript)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/.../abg.js (23.1KiB)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add an async attrib to the pagead script tag. defer too.

Comment: try using `defer` attribute along with or instead of `async`, as the hint explicitly recommends deferring.

Comment: @sabithpocker Tried both. But no change. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing wrong. It's just a recommendation to put script at the end of the page for speed. But sometimes we just ignore this for necessity.
For example, you need to display the ad at the same time of you page contents.

Comment: Oddly "AdSense Custom Search Ads" does not have this issue. Any reason why it exists with "Adsense for content"?

Comment: Different ad types maybe use different script loading methods. If it uses a asynchronous way then PageSpeed would not give a warning